# Bypassing import in Python so that I don't have to upload multiple libraries and classes?

Tags: python, import

For example, I have a few python scripts, that link together and some libraries for it that need to be imported. I'm trying to reduce it to only one script.

So instead of:

`import library.py`

Can I just take the coding from library.py and put into the main script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits to the size of a `.py` file, so you can certainly perform the copy and paste (and edit) operations you have in mind.

Some caveats:

```
import library.py
```

is unlikely to do what you want: it imports a module named `py` from a package named `library`. Thus it requires the existence of a *directory* `library` with an `__init__.py` and a `py.py` in it (or `.pyc`, etc).  I suspect you mean `import library`.

Merging all the needed modules into one large `.py` file only works for modules for which you have Python sources (`.py`) -- you need different techniques if all you have for a module is bytecode `.pyc` or `.pyo`, and if any of the modules are native-code binary Python extensions (`.pyd` or `.so` or `.dylib` etc etc, depending on your system) that just won't work.

You may have to do some renaming, e.g. when you import two modules that both define name `foo` you'll have to alter one or both of those names `foo`.  That's because, via imports, you get *qualified* names (so there's no problem if `a.foo` and `b.foo` both exist), but without imports you get *bare* names so you'll need to disambiguate them "manually".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, but probably it won't increase readability or maintainability.

Anyway be careful if you use functions like this:

```
import library    
library.functionA()
```

If you copy the content of `library.py`, you have to rename the function call to just `functionA()`.